# how to reorder an item in itemscontrol by holding in item?

Tags: xaml, drag-and-drop, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

HI i try to reorder `items` in `ItemsControl` . when i set `ManipulationMode` of element in `ItemsControl` to `ManipulationModes.TranslateY` `ScrollView` dosent work. for this problem i change this `ManipulationMode` in `Holding` event but i faced a new problem. 
in my code,we need release finger after holding and touch again for moving. i need holding and moving finger to drag items not holding and release and touch again and moving. this release is to bad for me and users
please help me.

my code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                x:Name="todoList">

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{Binding Path=color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}"
                Height="75"
                x:Name="todoItem">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <Behaviors:DragReOrderBehavior />
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                        <Grid Background="{StaticResource itemGradient}">
                             <!--task text-->
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                       Margin="15,15,0,15" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       x:Name="taskText"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

and behavior:

```
 public class DragReOrderBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
    private static readonly int AutoScrollHitRegionSize = 80;

    private DispatcherTimer _autoScrollTimer;
    private FrameworkElement _dragItem;
    private int _initialDragIndex;
    private bool IsActive = false;
    private ItemsControl itemscontrolList;
    private ItemViewModel draggedItemVM;
    private MainViewModel VM;
    private ResettableObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> itemsListVm;
    private ScrollViewer _scrollViewer;
    // private SoundEffect _moveSound;
    public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; private set; }


    public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
    {
        AssociatedObject = associatedObject;
        var fw = (FrameworkElement)AssociatedObject;

        //fw.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateY | ManipulationModes.System;
        ////fw.ManipulationStarted += fw_ManipulationStarted;
        fw.Holding += fw_Holding;
        //fw.ManipulationDelta += fw_ManipulationDelta;
        //fw.ManipulationCompleted += fw_ManipulationCompleted;
        if (fw.RenderTransform == null || fw.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform == null)
        {
            fw.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        }
        // a timer which is used to periodically detect the position of the
        // item being dragged in order to allow auto-scroll behaviour
        _autoScrollTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _autoScrollTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
        _autoScrollTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            AutoScrollList();
            ShuffleItemsOnDrag();
        };

        // _moveSound = SoundEffect.FromStream(TitleContainer.OpenStream("Sounds/Windows XP Menu Command.wav"));
    }

    void fw_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (Math.Abs(e.Cumulative.Translation.Y) > Math.Abs(e.Cumulative.Translation.X))
       // {
        //var fw = (FrameworkElement)AssociatedObject;

        //fw.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateRailsY | ManipulationModes.System;
            IsActive = true;

            // locate the element being dragged
            _dragItem = AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
            itemscontrolList = AssociatedObject.Ancestors<ItemsControl>().OfType<ItemsControl>().FirstOrDefault();
            draggedItemVM = ((ItemViewModel)_dragItem.DataContext);
            VM = (MainViewModel)itemscontrolList.DataContext;
            itemsListVm = VM.Items;
            _scrollViewer = itemscontrolList.Descendants<ScrollViewer>()
                              .Cast<ScrollViewer>()
                              .SingleOrDefault();
            _dragItem.SetVerticalOffset(0);
            _dragItem.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
            _dragItem.ManipulationDelta += fw_ManipulationDelta;
            _dragItem.ManipulationCompleted += fw_ManipulationCompleted;
            _dragItem.UpdateLayout();
            itemscontrolList.UpdateLayout();

            _initialDragIndex = itemsListVm.IndexOf(draggedItemVM);

            // fade out the items in the list, other than the dragged one
            foreach (var item in itemscontrolList.GetItemsInView()
                                          .Where(i => i.DataContext != draggedItemVM))
            {
                item.Animate(1.0, 0.7, "Opacity", 300, 0);
            }

            _autoScrollTimer.Start();
       // }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The ListView & GridView support reordering items. How about thinking of using them?

First you can disable this feature by setting  `CanDragItems` `CanReorderItems` `AllowDrop` to false and when you hold the item in your ListView then setting the properties above to true which will enable the Reorder feature.

Comment: hi JuniperPhoton tanks for answer. I tried this before, and this solution has a problem for windows phone. In windows phone, you need to set `ReorderMode` to `Enabled`, and this action cause that dont select any items in `holding` event . and you need release your finger after holding and touch again for moving. like my solution. is that any way to update tuch input?

Comment: Well it's true though. The experience of using ListView's reorder feature  looks so not elegant . Now I am considering writing this on my own.

Comment: I need reorder system like reorder tile in start menu.do you know how work it in windows phone?